# How can I find just the kth-nearest neighbor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I have a dataframe with almost 4000000 entries. Based on 3 features I want to find the distance between each point and its 1000th nearest neighbor. So far I've tried it like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors    
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1000)
nbrs = neigh.fit(df[features])
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(df[features])
```

Afterwars i would slice the `distances` array to get an array with just the distance to the 1000th nearest neighbor for each entry, because that's the only one I care about. However I don't get that far, because I don't have enough memory for an array with shape (4000000, 1000).
Is there a way where I can save just the distance to the 1000th neighbor and discard all other 999?

Background is that I'm trying to find a good fit for epsilon to run an DBSCAN algorith, but apparently my datapoints are too close to each other. I've already tried the code above for 5 and 100 neighbors. However besides from some outliers the distance is pretty much 0.
[Quantiles for distances to the 100th neighbor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPsDZ.jpg)

Comment: Try using a KDTree: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
x = np.random.randn(4000000,3)
kdt = KDTree(x)

closest_1000th =[]
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    dist, _ = kdt.query(x[i,:].reshape(1,-1),1000)
    closest_1000th.append(dist[0, -1])
```

On my 4Gb RAM laptop it took about 1hr to complete this task.

Hat tip @bogovicj.

Comment: glad you wrote up the details +1

Comment: @bogovicj You may wish to wrote yours and I will upvote! (none of my authentic attempts worked, this is why)

Comment: Hi, I think there is a syntax error with the slicing, but I get the idea. Thank you